# Has anyone finished Lovecraft's Azathoth?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, cthulhu-mythos

Lovecraft only wrote a [short fragment](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Azathoth) of [Azathoth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azathoth_%28short_story%29). Has anyone (fairly well-known) tried to write the whole story in Lovecraft's style?

Comment: Would this not go against Lovecraft's copyrights?

Comment: @apoorv: According to my Google Fu, Azathoth was written 1922 and is in the public domain, since the [Copyright Term Extension Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_Term_Extension_Act) only affects works from 1923 and onwards. (In the US.)

Comment: As this is interested in work by authors other than HPL, I've added a new tag which seems appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is no. We spent many hours and emailed a large number of people to check on this several years ago when we were doing research for a short movie/story a friend of ours had written.

But there are many writers who have used this creature in their writings, I guess you have already read the wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azathoth